# Crear un bucle para automatizar el código

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Teniendo en cuenta la longitud del array, automatizar este código con un bucle:

n.charAt(r) + n.charAt(s) + n.charAt(1+t) + n.charAt(2) + n.charAt(3+t) + n.charAt(4)...

para que devuelva a la consola: badcfehgjilknm

```js
 function array(n) {
   
  let s= 0;
  let r=1;
  let t=2;
  
  return n.charAt(r) + n.charAt(s) + n.charAt(1+t) + n.charAt(2) + n.charAt(3+t) + n.charAt(4) + n.charAt(5+t) + n.charAt(6) + n.charAt(7+t) + n.charAt(8) + n.charAt(9+t) + n.charAt(10);
}

console.log(array("abcdefghijklmn")); //badcfehgjilk
```

Comment: Hola, me puedes decir si la respuesta dada te fue útil, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
function array(n) 
{       
   let s= 0;
   let r=1;
   let t=2;
   let texto = n.charAt(r) + n.charAt(s);
   
   for (let i = 1; i < N; i += 2)
   {
      texto += n.charAt(i + t) + n.charAt(i + 1);
   }

   return texto;
}
```

Inicializamos las **variables s, r, t** como lo haces hasta ahora. Lo nuevo esta en que declaramos una nueva **variable llamada texto**, la cual inicializamos de la forma:

```
let texto = n.charAt(r) + n.charAt(s);
```

Posteriormente vendría el **ciclo for**, el cual se ejecutará desde **1 hasta N**, siendo **N** el limite q tu decidas (10, 1000, etc., lo decides tu). Este ciclo inicializa su **variable i** en **1** y se va incrementando de dos en dos:

```
i += 2
```

De esta forma nos movemos por los impares armando la secuencia que deseas de la forma:

```
texto += n.charAt(i + t) + n.charAt(i + 1);
```

Por ultimo al salir del ciclo retornamos la **variable texto**.